# Wordpress - Woocommerce shop order search in admin bar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

One of my client asks me to add a search form in the admin bar of his Woocommerce shop.

He wants that when he filled up the input with a shop order id that exists, it directly goes to the admin edit page of the shop order.
Else, it will do a basic search in the shop orders lists. He wants it in the admin bar because it is in front and in back.

I have done this piece of code that works, but I'm not sure if this is secured enough and if the redirect condition is right. I'm not able to find something about it on the web.

So I'm here to ask you if this is secured enough and if i won't get redirection problem ? And maybe I'm doing it wrong ?

```
// Add shop order search in the admin bar
function admin_bar_shop_order_form() {
  global $wp_admin_bar;

  $search_query = '';
  if (!empty($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {

    $search_query = !empty($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : '';

    if($search_query) {
        $order = get_post($search_query);

        if($order) {
            wp_redirect(get_edit_post_link($order->ID, ''));
            exit;
        }
    }
  }

  $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
    'id' => 'admin_bar_shop_order_form',
    'parent' => 'top-secondary',
    'title' => '<form method="get" action="'.get_site_url().'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order" style="display: flex; padding: 5px; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
      <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher une commande" value="' . $search_query . '" style="border:0; width:150px; height:100%; padding:0 10px; margin: 0;line-height:1em; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"/>
      <button class="button button-primary" style="cursor: pointer; height: auto; line-height: 1; padding: 0 10px; border: 0;background: #0085ba;color: #fff; font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif; ">Chercher</button>
      <input name="post_type" value="shop_order" type="hidden">
    </form>'
  ));
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'admin_bar_shop_order_form');
```

Comment: You just should replace `if($order){` by `if($order && $order->post_type == 'shop_order'){` to avoid displaying wrong posts when the ID is not an order ID … Otherwise your code is secure.

Comment: Oh yes of course ! Thank you for this. And you don't think that the redirection could be fired at  another place on the website ? A place where the two first condition could be fired ?

Comment: Maybe, but it will not change things in a deep way… For me your code works just fine and I don't see any redirection problem (adding that little condition in your if statement), but may be I am wrong… I hope not :)

Comment: Ok, great :) Thank you a lot !